# How to route ipv6 to an openvz container?

Tags: networking, ipv6, openvz, proxmox, ovh

My hosting provider, OVH, offers me a /64 ipv6 block.

I'm pretty new to ipv6 and a bit of a newbie in networking in general.

I was able to route an ipv6 on my proxmox server by properly configuring my `/etc/network/interfaces` and setting up an ipv6 address.

I can ping to and from it another ipv6 server.

Now, I'd like to assign addresses of the block to my openvz container.

But I don't really know how to do that.

I'm used to their vrack technology but it works differently because the ips are assigned the vrack itself and routed on the server.

I already tried to set up a new ipv6 ip address in the proxmox interface but either I misconfigured the ipv6 or it is not the way to go.

I'm pretty sure there is something to do with properly configuring a gateway and / or routes to it or something, but I don't know where to start.

Any ideas?

Comment: each network segment should be a /64, you'll want a /60 or even better a /48 if you're selling v6 connectivity services, anywhere you'd assign a static public ip you would want a /64 v6 subnet

Comment: OVH's support for IPv6 is terribly limited, and largely unusable for most such purposes without a lot of nasty hackery. The last time I checked, they had no plans to do IPv6 properly...

Answer (score 0):

As you are using openvz, you need to make sure ipv6 is working properly on Host/server.
Once you are able to ping ipv6.google.com from host node.

Assign ipv6 to your openvz container:

> vzctl set vpsid --ipadd ipv6_addr --save

Now Enter the vps and try to ping ipv6.google.com, it should work fine.

You may refer below link for more information:
https://openvz.org/IPv6